# Auto update chrome extensions outside web store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, auto-updates

Chrome automatically updates your installed extensions if they where installed through the web store. On the other hand, if you're using an extension that isn't posted there, you can manually add it to chrome, but you can't auto update the extension. You have to download the updated extension, open the extension page and drag/drop the new file there to update it.

Is there any way to auto update extensions outside the web store? I don't know if its possible to add the extension web as trusted URL for autoupdate or something like that, so Chrome would also check for updates there.

Comment: If Chrome doesn't know WHERE to get the update then it can't install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution has been described by Google:

> If you're hosting your own extension or app, you need to add the
>   "update_url" field to your manifest.json file, like this: `{   "name":
>   "My extension",   ...   "update_url":
>   "http://myhost.com/mytestextension/updates.xml",   ... }`

See https://developer.chrome.com/apps/autoupdate#update_url for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Autoupdate for off-store apps **is no more available** because of new security rules:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate

> As of M33, Windows stable/beta channel users can only download extensions hosted in the Chrome Web Store (see Protecting Windows users from malicious extensions).

More information:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2811969?p=ui_remove_non_cws_extensions

The only way to use these "private" extensions without the store is to remove the `update_url` key from the **manifest.json** and update them manually by drag'n'drop new versions to the extensions page.